# How to align the contents in longtable?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, longtable

I would like all the three lines of texts displayed by the pdf document generated by the following code to be aligned to the second line of text.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, pdftex, english, 10.25pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[top=1cm, bottom=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{setspace}


\newcommand{\tabitem}{~~\llap{\textbullet}~~~~~}


\definecolor{color}{RGB}{0,0,225}
\setitemize{itemsep=0em,leftmargin=*,labelsep=6.3mm}
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\begin{document}


\LARGE \textbf{Curriculum Vitae}\\
\normalsize
\setlength{\LTpre}{0pt}\setlength{\LTpost}{0pt}
\begin{spacing}{0.9}
\begin{longtable}[l]{@{}p{49mm}p{110mm}}
\arrayrulecolor{color}\toprule
\vspace{3mm}
\underline{\textbf{Personal Data}} \\

\textbf{Name} & abcde\\

\end{longtable}
\end{spacing}

\end{document}
```

I tried around with option in longtable `\indent`, `\noindent` and so on, but can still not obtain the effect I want.

Current pdf:

[image]

How can these two problems be solved?

Comment: To me it is a bit unclear how exactly the desired alignment should look like. Is this what you want to achieve? https://i.stack.imgur.com/cj16w.png

Comment: the code you post does not produce the output that you show, Name and abcde are on the same line, also you get warnings from the incorrect  option 1.25pt and from the  incorrect `\\ ` after Curriculum Vitae.

Comment: @leandriis Yes. I want all lines to be aligned vertically (Sorry for the late reply.) (Although I think that the first line is a little to the right instead of being completely aligned to the other two lines.)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Sorry, I just had time to correct the question.

Answer (score 0):

Put the title within the `longtable` with a `\multicolumn`.

Leave out the `\vspace{3mm}` and use `\\[3mm]` instead.

Shorten the column width to avoid `Overfull \hbox` warning.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, english]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[top=1cm, bottom=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{setspace}

\newcommand{\tabitem}{~~\llap{\textbullet}~~~~~}

\definecolor{color}{RGB}{0,0,225}
\setitemize{itemsep=0em,leftmargin=*,labelsep=6.3mm}
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\begin{document}
    \setlength{\LTpre}{0pt}\setlength{\LTpost}{0pt}
    \begin{spacing}{0.9}
        \begin{longtable}[l]{@{}p{40mm}p{100mm}}
            \multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{\LARGE\textbf{Curriculum Vitae}}\\
            \arrayrulecolor{color}\toprule
            \underline{\textbf{Personal Data}}\\[3mm]
            \textbf{Name} & abcde\\
        \end{longtable}
    \end{spacing}
\end{document}
```

[image]